# can I listen to any cross-domain iframe events?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

Are there any events that I can listen to on an iframe on a different domain?  For example,  have this page on domain1:

```
<html>
<body>
  <iframe src="domain2.com"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

What events can I listen to with regard to the contentWindow of the iframe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this. In newer browsers, you can use window.postMessage to communicate across domains between windows (works for iframes too):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

For older browsers, you can change the URL fragment for the location of the iframe to pass messages back and forth. You can use a separate iframe just to pass messages to avoid polling:
http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-domain-iframe-communication-without-location-polling

Answer (score 0):

I dont see how this should be a problem (having an iframe from another domain in IE) perhaps your issue is that you are opening files straight from your computer... Once these are files are hosted you should not see this problem occur.